# AJAX requests and possible server file structures

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-structure

I'm developing an HTML page which has multiple AJAX requests using JQuery.

I'm using the `POST` method and each request I make is to the same file, let's call this file ***X***.
File ***X*** has a non static functionality, meaning that if I want to call function ***Y*** from file ***X*** then I have to somehow signify to file ***X*** that I want it to only run function ***Y*** and return this value.

My server language is PHP and I will give an example of the situation below.

```
$.ajax({
    url  : "X.php",
    data : {
        function_to_call: "Y"
    },
    type : "POST",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data)
    },
});
```

The problem is that I keep adding new functions to file ***X***. I do this by simply adding different values in the `function_to_call` field and then simply using if statements to check the value of `function_to_call` and then running this function or code. I have added many functions to file ***X*** and now file ***X*** is to large and hard to organize and debug.

What are my other options to solve this problem and what are the benefits and disadvantages of these options?

Comment: Actually what you're doing *is not bad*, just disorganized. Consider grouping like functions in separate scripts and change the URL as needed.

Comment: Simplest way would be to just split up the files and call different files.  You could also consider using an mvc framework like laravel.  Then your urls would route to controller actions that would run your desired code and return data

Comment: You should also think about using variable function calls http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php. I would wrap the functions in a class so I could use method_exists to trap errors/bad post data. Either way you would not need any IF/SWITCH statemenst to call the required function, simply use the posted value as a variable funciton call.

Comment: You really just have two choices.  1) Break groups of related functions into separate PHP files and change the client to call those other files or 2) Organize the code cleaner in file X so you branch early in the file to different functions within that file which just makes the implementation feel cleaner.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it is about design philosophy, and therefore is on-topic for the Programmers.StackExchange site.